# Html image bigger than div border

Tags: html, css

My image is higher than my `div`, how do I tell my `div` to resize if something inside it is bigger? Here's my code:

```
<div {% if editable %}style="overflow-wrap: break-word; border-color: grey; border-style: solid; border-radius: 25px"{% else %}style="border-color: grey; border-style: solid; border-radius: 25px"{% endif %}>
        <h4>{{ new.header }}</h4>
        <p><img src="{{ new.file.url }}" style="max-width: 250px; float: left; height: auto">{{ new.text|safe }}</p>
        <p align="right">Дата: <strong>{{ new.added }}</strong></p>
        {% if editable == True %}
            <a href="{% url 'create_news' %}?news_id={{ new.pk }}" style="display: inline; float: right; padding-right: 5px; margin: 0">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning">изменить</button>
            </a>
            <form onsubmit="return confirm('Вы точно хотите удалить новость?');" method="post" style="display: inline; float: right; padding-right: 5px; margin: 0" action="{% url 'news_delete' news_pk=new.pk %}">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">удалить</button>
            </form>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
```

[image: Here's a picture of what it looks like]

Comment: try to add class `clearfix` to your container div.

Comment: Is your `div` is `fixed` `height`?

Answer (score 0):

The image is floated, so it *can*  go out of its parent container. To avoid that, you can add `overflow: auto` to the parent container (i.e. the `div` your HTML example code starts with) That way, the whole floated image will be *inside*  its parent and the border will go around it.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried clearfix as Ahmed Tag Amer suggested, it worked.